# Reputation earned and question titles are crammed together on activity drop-down

Tags: bug, reputation, firefox, activity-dropdown

On a half screen window, on the rep drop down menu, the rep gained and the question its from run together. Can an extra space be added?

I'm running FF 17.0.7 on Win 7

[image]

Comment: Hmm, [I can't repro this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RCDkk.png) on Chrome latest, also Windows 7. I've earned a two-digit amount of reputation from an answer, but there's still plenty of space. Perhaps this is Firefox-specific?

Comment: I was able to repro on Chrome 28/Win 7 by reducing the window width to about 600 pixels.

Comment: No repro in FF 22.0 on Win 8.

Comment: This happens when you resize the browser down to around 730px or fewer pixels wide. Notice the top bar above it. The grey background only extends part way into the search box because body and container width are now too small. Haven't figured out a way to solve it yet. (Tested in Chrome 28)

Comment: @animuson Is it too hacky to add an `&nbsp;` in the `td` after the rep count?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Ya, a bit, since a space doesn't really make sense at the end of a cell like that. A better solution would be to add padding to the cells so they always space apart. I was trying to figure out how to make the min-width work. Adding `min-width: 980px` to body makes the top bar expand to its correct size, but doesn't make the dropdown expand to the size it's supposed to be.

Comment: This is just the subjective question spacing feature at work.  Of course it should look this way, can't tell fact from fiction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a CSS guru by a long shot, but it seems like a simple fix to add a minimum width to the reputation column. That way, it stays the same size, no matter how small you make the page.

We've got a width there now of 40px. The minimum width could be the same, or slightly smaller.

```css
.profile-popup .profile-stats table .profile-table-rep-col1 {
    width:     40px;
    min-width: 40px;  /* <-- add this */
}
```

[image]

I had initially considered making the entire pop-up window a fixed width, since it's *mostly* fixed as it is. It does shrink a tiny bit, wrapping things like the recent badges to the next line. I'm not sure if this is by design, though, or just a happy accident.